# Switching back to the Default View if a Workflow approval is rejected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, workflow, infopath, infopath-rules

I've set up an InfoPath 2013 Form Load rule to switch view after a form is filled in and submitted. Works fine.

How would I switch back to the original Default view for the user to edit the form if it's rejected?

Comment: Actually I'm wondering if I could switch the views in the Workflow as opposed to InfoPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a field in the InfoPath form "FormView" with a default value of 0.
2. Promote the field to SharePoint.
3. Add a Form Load rule to switch to the original view if FormView = 1.
4. In your workflow, if the approval is rejected, update the FormView field to 1.

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a dream. I'd just add that you need to check, the 'Don't run other rule' box on this rule.